# [MySQL]Insert a value depending on a condition

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm studying MySQL so I'm a bit new to all this stuff, but the last time I asked you guys, you proved to be really helpful, so perhaps you can help me again because I haven't been able to find the answer on my own.

Ok, so the thing is, I need to add a new column to an already existing table, and it should be like:

```
ALTER TABLE `medicos` 
ADD COLUMN `tipo_medico` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'indiferente' AFTER `sueldo`;
```

Now I'm supposed to run an INSERT instruction to add the data there. After adding that column, the table looks like this:

[image]

These values equal to: Medic_number, Surnames, Speciality, Day of birth, University, Wage and Medic_type (the new column I've added). The data I add on all the columns except the last one doesn't really matter, but the last column must be filled following the next conditions:

-By default, it'll be "indiferente" (that's working).

-If a medic has studied in an university ending in -a (i.e. Valencia), it'll say "Excellent".

-If a medic is 40 years old or older, it'll say "Expert".

Now, I know how to do these conditions ("... university like = '%a'", etc), but I don't know how to add that into the INSERT instruction. This is what I've gotten so far:

```
insert into medicos values ('A021', 'Apellidos :D', 'Loquesealogia', '1970-03-14', 'Valencia', '3500');
```

That adds everything but the last column, which is the one where I'm lost. What can I do to tell the INSERT instruction to, depending on which of the previously named conditions are true, add one value or another?

I hope I've been clear enough, I'm not a native English speaker so I'm sorry if that wasn't good enough. Also I've tried to format the codes this time, I hope that'll work.

Thanks.

Comment: try insert select... you can user some regular select algorithm in the select part to determine how many records need to be inserted, or what should be inserted anyway.

Comment: Have you considered using a `view` instead?  What if the data is updated?  Then you could just use a `case` statement when selecting the data.

Comment: No, sadly I haven't, I'm a bit too confused with this exercise in particular, but I'll give that some space in my brain, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case when we need to apply a logic on column values before a record is inserted. I would suggest creating a `BEFORE INSERT trigger` on this table, which will be automatically executed by MySql before each record is inserted.

We can write the logic to determine the value of last column depending upon values supplied for the other columns. Have a look at [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php) link for trigger example.

If the requirement here is to do a one time bulk insert then, we can drop this trigger once insertion is complete.

Comment: Hm, I don't think we've studied that yet.. That leaves me a bit confused, am I perhaps going too far with the stuff I'm trying? lol. That seems pretty handy tho, so I'll try it out :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to do it either with BEFORE INSERT trigger as Darshan Mehta recommends, or do your logic in the programming side, or with a stored procedure.

Still it is doable at query time, so to answer your question specifically, try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO medicos (num_colegiado, apellidos, especialidad, fecha_nac, universidad, sueldo, tipo_medico) SELECT 'A021', 'Apellidos :D', 'Loquesealogia', '1970-03-14', 'Valencia', '3500', IF('Loquesealogia' like '%a','Excellent',IF(DATE_ADD('1970-03-14', interval 40 YEAR)>NOW(),'Expert','indiferente'))
```

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful, thank you very much!
There's a problem tho, it gives me a 1064 error, and I can't find what part of the instruction is wrong, altho it seems to be around the YEAR)>NOW() part, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh it was a typo, I've written DATEADD instead of DATE_ADD, the query is fixed, try now.

Comment: Nope, sadly I can't make it work. I've fixed the typo (thanks!) and it adds the new medic I want it to, but the column that should change doesn't. It stays as "indiferente", no matter how old the medic is or where he's studied. I'm going to go to bed now tho, but thank you very much for your help, this will surely be handy, I'll try to make it work tomorrow.

Comment: Execute only the select part and see what the last column is: SELECT 'A021', 'Apellidos :D', 'Loquesealogia', '1970-03-14', 'Valencia', '3500', IF('Loquesealogia' like '%a','Excellent',IF(DATE_ADD('1970-03-14', interval 40  YEAR)>NOW(),'Expert','indiferente'))  the result is Excellent